# C#: how to add 2 values in ComboBox from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have TWO questions, first how to add 2 values and second is: if we add 2 values so we need to change the code when we save `combo-box` value in database (second question with code I also ask from end of this question)?

I need to add 2 values from table `dep_Id` and `dep_Name` in `ComboBox; like this:

```
(Department ID: Department Name)
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo]. SelectComoboxData_SP
AS
    SELECT dep_Id, dep_Name 
    FROM department

    RETURN 0
```

This is the C# code:

```
public void updateDepartmentList()
{
    refresh_DataGridView();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectComoboxData_SP", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            com_boxDepartment.Items.Add(dr["dep_Id"]);
            com_boxDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("<<<INVALID SQL OPERATION \n" + ex);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Let me also know when I select any department from the combobox so now I wrote this code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dId", com_boxDepartment.Text);
```

for saving by id, so when add 2 values in combobox so we need to change anything?

Comment: Hi Hassan, it isn't clear what you are asking. In what way does the code in the question not work? Can you show the declaration of com_boxDepartment?

Answer (score 0):

If it were my C# I'd do it more like this (though I'd use strongly typed datasets)

```
public void updateDepartmentList()
{
    refresh_DataGridView();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectComoboxData_SP", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    com_boxDepartment.DataSource = dt;
    com_boxDepartment.DisplayMember = "dep_Name";
    com_boxDepartment.ValueMember = "dep_Id";
}
```

Your combo will show "History Department" for example, but when you ask it for the `.SelectedValue` it will return e.g. 2 (the id for the history department)